# Where are the methods of the Graphics class?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I'm trying to reuse a class that I implemented a long time ago in Windows Forms in a new WPF project. This class overrides the `OnRender` method that uses an object `Graphics` that draws various objects on the form. Now that I'm using my class in WPF, I have substituted the `Graphics` object with the `DrawingContext` object, but some methods of the `Graphics` class aren't implemented. In particular the methods `FillPie`, `FillEllipse`, `DrawBeziers` are the ones that I need.
Does a class exist that implements these methods? How can I implement these methods?

Comment: WPF uses retained graphics... You don't get a callback for every paint. Instead using WPF graphics primitives you compose what you want to render and where and The WPF rendering engine takes care of the rest

Comment: therefore, I would draw the figures in the drawing mode? The problem is that these figures represent markers of a GMaps and dimensions change depending on the zoom and some parameters that are set in the constructor.

Comment: In theory these markers can be databound to ZOOM and other parameters so that they update automatically when dependent parameters change

Comment: I thought to redraw the figure in the onResume method as I did before. I can do that? Can you show me examples of how to build such figures as beziers, cone or ellipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple example of how something like this could work in practice.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="500"
        Height="500">
    <StackPanel>
        <Slider Name="PositionSlider"
                Margin="10"
                Maximum="50"
                Minimum="1"
                Value="10" />
        <Canvas Width="300" Height="300">
            <Path Fill="Gold"
                  Stroke="Black"
                  StrokeThickness="1">
                <Path.Data>
                    <EllipseGeometry Center="150,150"
                                     RadiusX="{Binding ElementName=PositionSlider,
                                                       Path=Value}"
                                     RadiusY="{Binding ElementName=PositionSlider,
                                                       Path=Value}" />
                </Path.Data>
            </Path>
        </Canvas>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

The above WPF shows a simple slider and a circle. The radius of the circle is databound to the value of the slider. As you move the slider the circle because bigger or smaller. In your old world when the slider ( ie. your zoom state changed) you will get a repaint in which you will draw a bigger smaller circle. But in the WPF world this is taken care of by dependency properties and databinding.

[image]

The above example is very elementary , you can do more complicated things by doing multibinding bindings with value converters and objects implementing dependency properties and INotifyPropertyChanged all of which is too much to explain in one answer.

Comment: Great Example! Thanks... how can I draw geometric figures that are not "native" in wpf? as beziers or arch? for the arch I found an extension method of DrawingContext class, but how do I bind the properties? the figure is drawn programmatically and not through xaml?

Comment: [Geometries How-to Topics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750410) deals with things like beziers etc.... What do you mean by arch... do mean arc ?

Comment: perfect, thank you for your help! yes, I meant arc. Sorry for my bad English